# Low Flash AS3 Performance

Tags: performance, flash, actionscript-3, 3d

I'm working on a game coded in AS3 using the Alternativa3D 7.8 engine and it just doesn't have the FPS I was hoping to achieve with it and I'm trying to fully understand why. I get it that having 3D objects in a scene can be very taxing on performance but I'm using only a very limited number of 3d objects and each of those has a relatively small polygon count.

I'm wondering if there is something else like a memory leak causing this on top of the actual rendering of the scene.

I'd like to figure out a way to view how the performance is being distributed in my code to see if there are certain areas that are causing this. I usually only get about 10-15 FPS on my computer and I'd like to get that to around a constant 20-24 or higher if possible.

Comment: I don't think anyone can answer your question without seeing the code. You need to do tests by yourself - disable some parts of the code and see if it affects the frame rate, then disable other parts and check the frame rate, etc. and eventually you might find where the bottleneck is.

Comment: A good start would be to use the 8.x engine, that seems to be using Stage3D which is hardware accelerated. 7.x runs purely on software and will without a doubt be orders of magnitude slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this question should be downvoted necessarily, though it is a bit broad. OP is asking about general performance tips for AS3 applications.

It's true that we can't give him specific pointers without seeing his code, but we could still provide him with more general tips/tricks. Here's some analysis, pretty general:

I don't think your performance problems necessarily have anything to do with your 3D, though they might. The instant the game world comes on screen even the mouse movement is tremendously slowed, whereas the instant I pause it the framerate improves - which suggests to me that you are doing a lot of iteration and calculation on every frame.

I'd start with this: do you have any computationally intensive loops going on inside of your main game loop? For instance, I see that you're working with sea level as it effects landmass - are you doing something like calculating all of your water properties on every frame?

Having a lot of "3D" objects isn't necessarily a problem, because a 3D object is just a set of points. They're more intensive to position than 2d objects because you're including an additional dimension, but not so much more intensive that a few 3d objects would cause this kind of performance. I don't think that they are your problem (though I could be wrong).

Rather, it's what kind of calculations you're performing. Look for loops, figure out what you can comment out and instantly see better performance, and then once you've isolated it see what you can do about caching the outputs of those computations so that you don't have to recalc them on every frame.

Cheers,
mb